# Showing that a set cannot be expressed as the local graph of a $C^1-$function over the $x-$axis or the $y-$axis near the origin.

Tags: analysis, inverse-function-theorem

Consider the function $h(x,y)=(x−y^2)(x−3y^2)$, $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Show that the set $\{(x,y) | h(x,y) = 0\}$ cannot be expressed as the local graph of a $C^1-$function over the $x-$axis or the $y-$axis near the origin.

I have no idea where to begin. I can only draw a graph and say that it fails the vertical line test. How to write it in a rigorous manner?

I have been taught Implicit Function Theorem. So, probably a hint along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove that  $0$ is a regular value for a $C^\infty$ function if and only if the locus of that $C^1$ function is locally the graph of a real  $C^1$ function on the $x-$ axis or the $y-axis$. So you must prove that $0$ is not a regular value for $h$ that means that

$\nabla(h)(x,y)\neq 0$ for all $(x,y)\in Z(h)$

but in $0$ your function is such that

$\nabla(h)(0)=0$

Comment: What is regular value? We have not been taught that.

Comment: 0 is a regular value for $h$ if and only if for each $x\in $h^{-1}(0)$ then $\nabla(h)(x)\neq 0$